# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[2,7,11,15]' is leetcode wrong?

Tags: python, list, function, integer, literals

i have written the program in leetcode and line no 2 here shows invalid literal for int with base 10.(this is not whole program) i have just included the part which shows error.

```
 def twosum(nums, target):
    **  nums=list(nums)**
        leng=len(nums)
       
                   
nums=map(int,input().split(" "))
target=int(input())
sum=s.twosum(nums,target)



same program was properly working in python idle.
```

Comment: Please, fix the indentation and make sure you show the exact code. Text format is not possible inside a code block, in case you added the enclosing `**` with that intention.

Comment: It sounds like you're entering a string like `[2,7,11,15]` instead of `2 7 11 15`.  As a side note, you should just use a list comprehension instead of `map` -- that way you get a list in the first place and don't need to worry about converting `map` to `list` inside your function.  As another side note, you shouldn't make a variable called `sum` since it will shadow the builtin `sum` function (which is something that will probably actually be very useful in your `twosum` function).